# datepicker is not working in mvc4

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui

I beginner in mvc Going to create application.I want to display datepicker in my application on textbox.I have written code in view .cshtml

```
<link href="~/Content/themes/base/minified/jquery.ui.datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#date").datepicker();
     });
</script>
<h2>Index</h2>
<input type="text" id="date" />
```

When I click on textbox it is not working Please help if anyone have any  idea about this.

Comment: Is jQuery UI included in the page?  Any errors on the JavaScript console?  The code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/5e4d2k00/

Comment: Reformat code for readability, added relevant tags.

Answer (score 0):

In you bundleConfig.cs file first write `**bundleTable.bundles.Usecdn = true**` 
  after this add you CDN links into head section of layout.cshtml and after that 
write this code in your head section of layout.cshtml

```
 <script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#datepicker").datepicker();
     });
 </script>
```

here asign `id = datepicker` to the input where you want to show

Answer (score -1):

Include `jQuery UI` in your script, add `class="datepicker"` where you want your datepicker to apear, and add this function:

```
$(function() {
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();

});
```

Comment: How is this different from what the OP is already doing?  What's wrong with using an `id` instead of a `class`?

Comment: But what if I want datepicker to appear in more than one place in my form?

Comment: Then you put more than one element on the page.  How is that related to the question?  This answer suggests that the problem in the original question is that an `id` was used as a selector.  That is not the problem.  An `id` is a valid selector in jQuery.

Comment: The point is that in both cases it works just fine, and I don't know why my answer made you so mad..

Comment: $(function() {
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>

<p>Date: <input type="text" class="datepicker"></p>            have done on this way but still not working